# add organization to subject field with terraform's vault provider

Tags: terraform, ssl-certificate, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to provision a kubernetes cluster by creating all the certificates through vault first. It somehow makes it easy in the context of terraform, because I can insert all this information in the cloudinit config, so I don't have to rely on a node being ready and then transfer data from one to another.

In any case, the problem that I have is that `vault_pki_secret_backend_cert` doesn't seem to support any change to the subject field except for `common_name` (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/resources/pki_secret_backend_cert), whereas kubernetes relies on these types of certificates where the organization is specified. For example:

> Subject: O = system:masters, CN = kube-etcd-healthcheck-client

I'm generating these certificates by directly using vault's intermediate certificate, so the private key is in vault. I cannot generate them separately, and I wouldn't want that anyway, because I'm trying to provision basically everything using terraform.

Any ideas how I can get around this issue?

Comment: This is how the Vault PKI secrets engine works, so appending to the subject would need to be external to the actual certificate management.

Comment: @MattSchuchard That's actually not true. I found out eventually: yo do that through roles: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/resources/cert_auth_backend_role
It's just that it's quite annoying that you have to do that and it's impractical if you have various certificates with different organizations. In my case, I was able to use just two roles for certificates which have the organization information and those who don't.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out the answer eventually. The only way to do this with terraform/vault seems to be configuring the backend role and add the `organization` parameter in that role:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/resources/cert_auth_backend_role.

For example, you define the role:

```json
resource "vault_pki_secret_backend_role" "etcd_ca_clients" {
  depends_on       = [ vault_pki_secret_backend_intermediate_set_signed.kube1_etcd_ca ]
  backend          = vault_mount.kube1_etcd_ca.path
  name             = "kubernetes-client"
  ttl              = 3600
  allow_ip_sans    = true
  key_type         = "ed25519"
  allow_any_name   = true
  allowed_domains  = ["*"]
  allow_subdomains = true
  organization     = [ "system:masters" ]
}
```

And here you tell vault to generate the certificate based on that role:

```
resource "vault_pki_secret_backend_cert" "etcd_healthcheck_client" {
        for_each = { for k, v in var.kubernetes_servers : k => v if startswith(k, "etcd-") }
        depends_on = [vault_pki_secret_backend_role.etcd_ca_clients]
        backend = vault_mount.kube1_etcd_ca.path
        name = vault_pki_secret_backend_role.etcd_ca_clients.name
        common_name = "kube-etcd-healthcheck-client"
}
```

The limitation makes no sense whatsoever to me, but if you don't a bulk of very different certificates, it's not all too bad and you don't have to repeat a lot of code.